# Ruby on Rails - Get polymorphic_id before_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, polymorphism

I have a two models:

**Polymorphic**

```
class Custo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :custavel, polymorphic: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :custavel, allow_destroy: true
  validates_presence_of :numero, :serie
  validates_uniqueness_of :numero, scope: :serie
end
```

**Another class**

```
class Pagamento < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :custo, as: :custavel
end
```

In general **numero** and **serie** are filled by user input, but *only* when the polymorphic is a **Pagamento** i need to fill the column **numero** with **custavel_id**.

Then, i tried it:

```
before_save :set_numero
def set_numero
  return unless custavel_type == 'Pagamento'
  write_attribute(:numero, custavel_id)
end
```

But it fails on validation because **custavel_id** doesn't exists yet. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the `callback` method

```
before_save :set_numero

def set_numero
  write_attribute(:numero, custavel_id) if custavel_type == 'Pagamento'
end
```